# What's wrong with my webdav setup?

Tags: mac-osx, webdav

I'm trying to set up a webdav server on my Mac running OS X 10.6.6. Here's my /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-dav.conf file:

```
Alias /webdav "/Library/WebServer/WebDAV"

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/WebDAV">
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all

   Dav On
   AuthType Digest
   AuthName WebDAV-Realm
   AuthUserFile "/usr/var/webdav.passwd"
</Directory>
```

From the Finder, I can use the connect command to connect to http://localhost/webdav/, which asks for my password, but I always get a connection failed error.

Comment: We could use more detail. What does is the exact error, what do your logs say?

Comment: And are you able to successfully load that URL in a browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use your configuration, I get the following error message in my error logs (`/var/log/apache2/error_log`):

```
[Mon Jan 24 20:18:54 2011] [error] [client ::1] The lock database could not be opened, preventing access to the various lock properties for the PROPFIND.  [500, #0]
[Mon Jan 24 20:18:54 2011] [error] [client ::1] A lock database was not specified with the DAVLockDB directive. One must be specified to use the locking functionality.  [500, #401]
```

This causes the Finder to return a "connection failed" message.  If you look at the example `httpd-dav.conf` provided by Apple, you'll see:

```
DavLockDB "/usr/var/DavLock"
```

So you need something like that in your own configuration. After adding the appropriate `DavLockDB` entry to my config file, it worked without any problems.  Documentation on `mod_dav_fs` can be found [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav_fs.html).

NB: You may also want to add a `require valid-user` directive to your directory configuration to prevent unauthorized access to the directory.